# Create instance in Kotlin and only set property if not null

Tags: kotlin

I have a data class that looks like this:

```
data class MyDataCass(val x: String, val y: String, 
                      val something: Something = Something(),
                      val somethingElse : SomethingElse = SomethingElse())
```

Since this class is going to be used from both Kotlin and Java I've also created a builder to make it easier to construct it from Java. The problem is that `something` and `somethingElse` are optional and I'd like to avoid duplication of the default values. This is essentially what I've tried:

```
data class MyDataCass(val x: String, val y: String, 
                      val something: Something = Something(), 
                      val somethingElse : SomethingElse = SomethingElse()) {

    class Builder() {
        private lateinit var x: String
        private lateinit var y: String
        private var something: Something? = null
        private var somethingElse: SomethingElse? = null

        // builder functions to set the properties defined above
        ...

        fun build() = MyDataCass(x, y, something = ??, somethingElse = ??)
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is to set `something` and `somethingElse` *only if they've been defined by the builder* (i.e. they are not `null`), otherwise I'd like to use the default values as defined by the data class constructor. I could of course change the build function to look like this:

```
fun build() = if (something == null && somethingElse == null) {
        MyDataCass(x, y)
    } else if(somethingElse == null) {
        MyDataCass(x, y, something = something)
    } else {
        MyDataClass(x,y, somethingElse = somethingElse)
    }
}
```

but I find this to be quite verbose and error prone. Is there a less verbose or more idiomatic way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported very well by the language, if there was a good solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44728519/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-default-value-on-a-non-optional-parameter-when-null-is) that would help you too.

With that said, here's what I could come up with that lets you have the default values declared just once - at the cost of duplicating other code, however:

```
data class MyDataCass(val x: String, val y: String,
                      val something: Something,
                      val somethingElse: SomethingElse) {

    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(x: String, y: String,
                            something: Something? = null,
                            somethingElse: SomethingElse? = null) =
                MyDataCass(x, y,
                        something ?: Something(),
                        somethingElse ?: SomethingElse())
    }

    class Builder {
        private lateinit var x: String
        private lateinit var y: String
        private var something: Something? = null
        private var somethingElse: SomethingElse? = null

        // builder functions to set the properties defined above
        // ...

        fun build() = MyDataCass(x, y, something, somethingElse)
    }
}
```

This way you can keep using the builder from Java, and in Kotlin the syntax that looks like is a call to the constructor is instead a call to the `invoke` function of the companion object, which has the default values. Your data class of course still has non-nullable types so that it's easier to use.

Comment: Nice workaround! What I ended up doing was to define the default values in an internal companion object and refer to them both from the builder and the data class constructor.